# How to see REST Request/Respons in Spring

Tags: java, serialization, spring-boot

## Background

Let's say we have a *@RestController* with the following method (**Spring Boot 1.3.5.RELEASE**):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/helloworld", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, String> helloWorld(@RequestBody Map<String, String> m) {
    m.put("Hello", "2");
    m.put("World", "1");
    return m;
}
```

And a *@Test* using **TestRestTemplate**:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();

@Test
public void testHelloWorld() {
    Map<String, String> request = new HashMap<>();
    request.put("Hello", "1");
    request.put("World", "2");
    Map<String, String> respons = this.restTemplate.postForObject("/helloworld", request, Map.class);
}
```

## Question

How can one print/log the actual *request/respons* being *sent/received*?

I.e how to print/log the serialized versions of the *request/respons*?

Answer (score 0):

This is availible on the level of request filters:

```
public class YourCustomFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
               ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        // your code here

    }

}
```

But, the question is: Would you really like to do this and because of what? Remember, that this is really error prone.

Comment: I want to see how the request/respons is structured so that I can for instance **POST** via the _curl_ command for testing. No particular other reason. With this approach, do I just have to log the _ServletRespons_ and _ServletRequest_ to achieve what is wanted?

Comment: In this case you can play with Postman (it is chrome extension). In this way you can in very easy way play with API. You can't log directly request/response to the file. You have to deserialize those objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aspect to log request and response

example snippet of request:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class InputLoggerAspect {

   private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InputLoggerAspect.class);

   @Autowired
   private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

   @Before(value = "valueToPointCut")
   public void before(JoinPoint pointcut) throws Exception {

      Object[] args = pointcut.getArgs();

      for (Object object : args) {
         LOGGER.info("{}:{}", object.getClass(), objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object));
      }

   }
}
```